# Q: Detecting Insert/Update/Delete on a Table using OCN and pass the "real_id" to UTL_HTTP.REQUEST on the callback?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to detect Insert, Update or Delete on a Table. I know I can't use QRCN for this so I'm trying to use OCN. What I'm trying to achieve is... when an Insert/Update is detected call "callback_iu" when a Delete is detected call 'callback_d'.

```
DECLARE

  qosflags      NUMBER;
  reginfo_iu    cq_notification$_reg_info;
  reginfo_d     cq_notification$_reg_info;
  regid_iu      NUMBER;
  regid_d       NUMBER;
  v_cursor      SYS_REFCURSOR;  
  opfilter_iu   NUMBER;
  opfilter_d    NUMBER;

BEGIN
   qosflags := DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.QOS_ROWIDS;
   opfilter_iu := DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.INSERTOP + DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.UPDATEOP;
   opfilter_d := DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.DELETEOP;


   reginfo_iu := cq_notification$_reg_info('callback_iu', qosflags,0, opfilter_iu, 0);
   regid_iu := DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.NEW_REG_START(reginfo_iu);

        OPEN v_cursor FOR 
           SELECT DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.QOS_ROWIDS, department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id
           FROM HR.departments
        CLOSE v_cursor;

   DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.REG_END;

   reginfo_d := cq_notification$_reg_info('callback_d', qosflags,0, opfilter_d, 0);
   regid_d := DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.NEW_REG_START(reginfo_d);

        OPEN v_cursor FOR 
           SELECT DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.QOS_ROWIDS, department_id, department_name, manager_id, location_id
           FROM HR.departments
        CLOSE v_cursor;

   DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.REG_END;

END;
```

I know that I can get ROWID and the **"real_id"** using QRCN like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE chnf_callback
  (ntfnds IN CQ_NOTIFICATION$_DESCRIPTOR)
IS

  event_type      NUMBER;
  tbname          VARCHAR2(60);
  numtables       NUMBER;
  operation_type  NUMBER;
  numrows         NUMBER;
  row_id          VARCHAR2(2000);
  numqueries      NUMBER;
  qid             NUMBER;
  real_id         NUMBER;

BEGIN

  event_type := ntfnds.event_type;

  numqueries :=0;
  IF (event_type = DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.EVENT_QUERYCHANGE) THEN
      numqueries := ntfnds.query_desc_array.count;
      FOR i in 1..numqueries LOOP

         qid := ntfnds.QUERY_DESC_ARRAY(i).queryid;
         numtables := 0;
         numtables := ntfnds.QUERY_DESC_ARRAY(i).table_desc_array.count;
         FOR j IN 1..numtables LOOP
           tbname := ntfnds.QUERY_DESC_ARRAY(i).table_desc_array(j).table_name;
           operation_type := ntfnds.QUERY_DESC_ARRAY(i).table_desc_array(j).Opflags;

           IF (bitand(operation_type, DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.ALL_ROWS) = 0)
           THEN
             numrows := ntfnds.query_desc_array(i).table_desc_array(j).numrows;
           ELSE
             numrows :=0;   /* ROWID INFO NOT AVAILABLE */
           END IF;

            /* The body of the loop is not executed when numrows is ZERO */
            FOR k IN 1..numrows LOOP
               Row_id := ntfnds.query_desc_array(i).table_desc_array(j).row_desc_array(k).row_id;

               select department_id into real_id from hr.departments where rowid = Row_id;
               -->INSERT IN NFROWCHANGES<--
               INSERT INTO nfrowchanges VALUES(qid, tbname, Row_id, real_id);

            END LOOP;  /* loop over rows */
         END LOOP;     /* loop over tables */
       END LOOP;        /* loop over queries */
  END IF;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

I also know that I can check **operation_type** to know if it's an Insert (2) or Update (4), but I can't make it work with Delete.

So how can I get ROWID and the **"real_id"** using OCN and pass it to UTL_HTTP.REQ on the callback?

```
DECLARE req  UTL_HTTP.REQ;
        resp UTL_HTTP.RESP;
BEGIN
    req := utl_http.begin_request(
            url    => 'localhost:3000/departments/'||real_id,
            method => 'GET'
        );

    resp := utl_http.get_response(r => req);

    utl_http.end_response(r => resp);

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know how to work with OCN, in this solution I'm using QRCN. Since I can't get row_id when a row is deleted, instead of deleting the row I created a new column called "Active", so when I want to "delete" a row I change "Active" from "Yes" to "No".

So here is the solution to send the "real_id" from the Inserted/Updated/"Deleted" row using UTL_HTTP.

anonymous block:

```
DECLARE

   l_reginfo CQ_NOTIFICATION$_REG_INFO;
   l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_regid   NUMBER;
   qosflags  NUMBER;

BEGIN

    qosflags := DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.QOS_QUERY + DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.QOS_ROWIDS;
    l_reginfo := cq_notification$_reg_info ('query_callback', qosflags, 0, 0, 0);

    l_regid := dbms_cq_notification.new_reg_start(l_reginfo);

    OPEN l_cursor FOR
        SELECT
            id,
            city_name,
            country_name,
            votes,
            active
        FROM hr.jsao_super_cities
        WHERE active = 'YES';
    CLOSE l_cursor;

    dbms_cq_notification.reg_end;

END;
/
```

callback:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE query_callback
  (ntfnds IN CQ_NOTIFICATION$_DESCRIPTOR)
IS

  event_type      NUMBER;
  numtables       NUMBER;
  operation_type  NUMBER;
  numrows         NUMBER;
  row_id          VARCHAR2(2000);
  is_active       VARCHAR2(20);
  numqueries      NUMBER;
  real_id         NUMBER;
  l_req  UTL_HTTP.REQ;
  l_resp UTL_HTTP.RESP;

BEGIN 

  event_type := ntfnds.event_type;

  numqueries :=0;
  IF (event_type = DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.EVENT_QUERYCHANGE) THEN
      numqueries := ntfnds.query_desc_array.count;
      FOR i in 1..numqueries LOOP

         numtables := 0;
         numtables := ntfnds.QUERY_DESC_ARRAY(i).table_desc_array.count;
         FOR j IN 1..numtables LOOP

           operation_type := ntfnds.QUERY_DESC_ARRAY(i).table_desc_array(j).Opflags;

           IF (bitand(operation_type, DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.ALL_ROWS) = 0)
           THEN
             numrows := ntfnds.query_desc_array(i).table_desc_array(j).numrows;
           ELSE
             numrows :=0;
           END IF;


            FOR k IN 1..numrows LOOP

               Row_id := ntfnds.query_desc_array(i).table_desc_array(j).row_desc_array(k).row_id;

               --getting "real_id"
               select id into real_id from hr.jsao_super_cities where rowid = Row_id;

                -- 2 = insert
                IF(operation_type = 2) THEN
                    l_req := utl_http.begin_request(
                        url    => 'localhost:3000/city/'||real_id,
                        method => 'GET'
                    );

                    l_resp := utl_http.get_response(r => l_req);

                    utl_http.end_response(r => l_resp);

                -- 4 = update
                ELSIF (operation_type = 4) THEN

                    select active into is_active from hr.jsao_super_cities where id = real_id;

                    IF (is_active = 'YES') THEN

                        l_req := utl_http.begin_request(
                            url    => 'localhost:3000/city/'||real_id,
                            method => 'GET'
                        );

                        l_resp := utl_http.get_response(r => l_req);

                        utl_http.end_response(r => l_resp);

                    ELSIF (is_active = 'NO') THEN

                        l_req := utl_http.begin_request(
                            url    => 'localhost:3000/delete/'||real_id,
                            method => 'GET'
                        );

                        l_resp := utl_http.get_response(r => l_req);

                        utl_http.end_response(r => l_resp);

                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;  /* loop over rows */
         END LOOP;     /* loop over tables */
       END LOOP;        /* loop over queries */
  END IF;



END query_callback;
/
```

I hope this can help someone else.

Comment: Very helpful! I am also trying to understand how to get the real-time in callback